# Is there a standard way to assign weekly data to years?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there a standard way in R to convert weekly (ISO weeks) data to yearly. The following method has the problem that it assigns 53 weeks to 2015 and 2020 and 52 weeks to most other years.

I realize some averaging will have to take place.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)

get_eurostat("demo_r_mwk_05")%>%
  mutate(Year = as.integer(substr(as.character(time), 1, 4)))

# A tibble: 2,070,969 × 7
   age   sex   unit  geo   time    values  Year
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <fct>    <dbl> <int>
 1 TOTAL F     NR    BG    2022W07   1567  2022
 2 TOTAL F     NR    CH    2022W07    714  2022
 3 TOTAL F     NR    CY    2022W07     63  2022
 4 TOTAL F     NR    DK    2022W07    613  2022
```

Comment: What type of "standard" are you looking for exactly? The ISO standard is normally good enough for most but it sounds like you don't like that standard for some years. What exactly do you want to happen in those cases? Keep in mind that the calendar does not evenly divide into anything and even has a different number of days each year. Dates and times are very messy,. How exactly do you define a "week"?

Comment: `ISOweek::ISOweek2date()` sounds like it will do what you want. My manual approach suggestion was going to be to join the data to a helper table where you've pre-calculated the date to ISOweek conversion for all the dates in your range.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to evenly distribute values over years so I can compare them. I'm aware of leap days, but the week problem is an order of magnitude larger. I guess dividing the weekly values evenly over seven days and then assign the days to years might be good enough.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds you explicitly do not want the approach that ISO weeks takes, which assumes weeks always have 7 days and adjusts which year they are assigned to. You might alternately look at `lubridate::yday` or `lubridate::decimal_date` and adjust to taste.